# Twitter Python-OAuth API with Proxy Support

Tags: python, twitter, proxy, oauth, signature

Does anyone know of any other Python twitter module's that have OAuth and Proxy support besides Python-OAuth2? Because it's broken for me and has started giving me "incorrect signature" errors.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) has OAuth support, along with a lot of other features.

I use it in one of my projects and have been very impressed with its API.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll look into using it - also I just started using `tweepy` as another alternative.